# CURL upload file box.com issue

Tags: curl, box

I am trying to use the [upload a file](https://docs.box.com/docs/getting-started-box-integration#section-upload-a-file) into *box.com* my account.

when i use the below command it throws the below error.

I am unable to figure out what is the syntax issue over here.

can anyone help me with it. ?

```
curl -g https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content -H "Authorization: Bearer Fn3A7dadfxSscUrfQbY7aSrj7ihR899TBgZ" -X POST -F attributes='{"name":"pappi.jpg", "parent":{"id":"0"}}' -F file=@pappi.jpg
```

> {"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"entity-body","message":"Invalid
>   value ''{name:pappi.jpg,'. Entity body should be a correctly nested
>   resource attribute name/value
>   pair"}]},"help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors","message":"Bad
>   Request","request_id":"93232892358c3571c303f0"}curl: (6) Could not
>   resolve host: parent:{id

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with a dev token and it seems to work.

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content 
-H "Authorization: Bearer <devtoken>" -X POST 
-F attributes='{"name":"ken.jpg", "parent":{"id":"0"}}' 
-F file=@ken.jpg

{"total_count":1,"entries":[{"type":"file","id":"149964282905","file_version":    {"type":"file_version","id":"159621506329","sha1":"078    8d369db76258c45b08be771ff4a55a43d9661"},"sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","sha1":"0788d369db76258c45b08be771ff4a55a43d9661","name":"ken.jpg","description":"","size":5079,"path_collection":{"total_count":1,"entries":[{"type":"folder","id":"0","sequence_id":null,"etag":null,"name":"All Files"}]},"created_at":"2017-03-21T14:48:46-07:00","modified_at":"2017-03-21T14:48:46-07:00","trashed_at":null,"purged_at":null,"content_created_at":"2017-03-21T14:48:46-07:00","content_modified_at":"2017-03-21T14:48:46-07:00","created_by":{"type":"user","id":"270956269","name":"Ken.Domen.Test","login":"ken.domen.test@nike.com"},"modified_by":{"type":"user","id":"270956269","name":"Ken.Domen.Test","login":"ken.domen.test@nike.com"},"owned_by":{"type":"user","id":"270956269","name":"Ken.Domen.Test","login":"ken.domen.test@nike.com"},"shared_link":null,"parent":{"type":"folder","id":"0","sequence_id":null,"etag":null,"name":"All Files"},"item_status":"active"}]}APYRDV30BA5D24:curl kdomen$
```